# SQLite s3db file to connect with android application

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the code that needs to be written to attach or connect a SQLite s3db file to connect with android application? Where must the code be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main activity setup your DB.

```
 private void setupDatabase() 
         {
                Dbhelper myDbHelper = new Dbhelper(getApplicationContext());
                myDbHelper = new Dbhelper(this);

                try {

                    myDbHelper.createDataBase();

                } catch (IOException ioe) {

                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

                }

            }
```

Comment: what is Dbhelper?? where do i place my database?

Comment: please tell me the complete code as i dont know about android coding

Comment: come on you should do sme research about it.try this link http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0

Comment: or try this video tutorial it has all about the android http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6