# SQLite database connection in android

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

I have a s3db database in SQLite. Now I want to attach or open it in the application? Please tell me what code needs to be written to connect to the database?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: Posting in [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10732315/1321873) is not going to get you the results that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give u an example with the help of that u can easily understand how can we show the data from the database on a textview. Below is the code in which the testdata is the name of the database which have user table in which 2 columns are present. i show the data of these 2 columns on 2 diff. textviews.

```
public class high_score extends Activity{
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase=null;
String Data="";
String Data1="";
String TableName="users";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.high_score);




        RelativeLayout main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

        try
        {
            mydatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("testdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor c=mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT name,score FROM "+TableName+" , null);
            int column1=c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int column2=c.getColumnIndex("max_score");
            c.moveToFirst();
            if(c!=null)
            {   
                do
                {
                    String Name=c.getString(column1);
                    int Score=c.getInt(column2);
                    Data=Data+Name+"\n";
                    Data1=Data1+Score+"\n";
                    System.out.println("name"+Name+" score"+Score);
                }while(c.moveToNext());
                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                TextView points=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.points);
                tv.setText(Data);
                points.setText(Data1);
                setContentView(main);

                }

             /*TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(Data);
            setContentView(tv);*/

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR","ERROR" ,ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(mydatabase!=null)
                mydatabase.close();
        }
```

you can easily access the data like this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want but if you want to get data from your database you can do it like this:

```
this.database = new ContactsDatabase(this, Contacts.DB_NAME, null, Contacts.startVersion).getWritableDatabase();
        this.cursor = this.database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, email, phone FROM contacts ORDER BY name ASC", null);
```

Check official guides.